# Finding the latest data of the object in the bundled data in Mongo

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
[
  {
    "_id": "",
    "at": IsoDate(2022-11-19 10:00:00),
    "areaId": 3,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "sec": 34,
        "x": 10.3,
        "y": 23.3
      },
      {
        "name": "a",
        "sec": 36,
        "x": 10.3,
        "y": 23.3
      },
      {
        "name": "b",
        "sec": 37,
        "x": 10.3,
        "y": 23.3
      }
      ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "",
    "at": IsoDate(2022-11-19 10:00:00),
    "areaId": 3,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "sec": 10,
        "x": 10.3,
        "y": 23.3
      },
      {
        "name": "b",
        "sec": 12,
        "x": 10.3,
        "y": 23.3
      }
      ]
  }
  ]
```

I have a table that indicates in what seconds people are in which area in packets of minutes. My goal here is to find the date the person with the specified name was last in the field with the most performance.

Can you help me for this?

Example output: Last date 'a' was found in polygon=3

2022-11-19 10:01:10 (with sec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

1. Use the first 3 steps to find the matching document
2. The 4th step is to add the seconds to to the `at` date

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {data: {$elemMatch: {name: inputName}}}},
  {$sort: {at: -1}},
  {$limit: 1},
  {$project: {
      res: {
        $dateAdd: {
          startDate: "$at",
          unit: "second",
          amount: {$reduce: {
              input: "$data",
              initialValue: 0,
              in: {$cond: [
                  {$eq: ["$$this.name", inputName]},
                  {$max: ["$$this.sec", "$$value"]},
                  "$$value"
              ]}
          }}
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/To2sMm7YmE8)

Comment: actually date is not a string, I wrote iso date as a string to show it there, how can we edit it?

Comment: Even simpler. The answer is updated accordingly